# using memmove in dynamic allocation in c

Tags: c

I tried to make an Insert function that gets dynamic allocated structure, its size and position.
After finishing the copy to temp pointer. I tried to copy back, but it does not work.

```
void Insert(Student *ptr, int n, int p)
{
    if(p < 1 || p > (n+1) )
{
    printf("Position out of Bound!\n");
    return;
}

Student *temp;
temp = (Student *)malloc( (n+1) * sizeof(Student));

// copy ptr to temp
memmove(temp, ptr, p * sizeof(Student));
memmove(temp+(p+1), ptr+(p+1), n * sizeof(Student));

// get info
printf("Enter the Roll number : ");
scanf("%d", &(temp+p)->rollNO);

printf("Enter the Student Name : ");
scanf("%s", (temp+p)->Name);

printf("Enter the Course : ");
scanf("%s", (temp+p)->Class);

printf("Enter the Mark1 : ");
scanf("%d", &(temp+p)->Mark1);

printf("Enter the Mark2 : ");
scanf("%d", &(temp+p)->Mark2);

(temp+p)->avg = ( (temp+p)->Mark1 + (temp+p)->Mark2 ) / 2;

printf("\n");

// realloc and copy back
ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(temp));

memmove(ptr, temp, sizeof(temp));

free(temp);
}
```

What should I use memcpy, memmove, or just equal operation?

---

I'm sorry for not explained well.
I will explain as flow,
1. get dynamic allocated student structure, number of structure, position to insert
2. make the temporary structure
3. copy the ptr to temp until position that the function got
4. copy the ptr to temp after position until the end of ptr
5. then get information to 'p' position of temp
6. reallocate the pointer size
7. copy back temp to ptr

and the main function is...

```
int main()
{
Student *Sptr;
int num; // get number by scanf

Sptr = (Student *)malloc(num * sizeof(Student));

int pos;
scanf("%d", &pos);

Insert(Sptr, num, pos);
num++;

}
```

The first and second memmove works and I checked, but whenever I tried to copy back temp to ptr, the value changes to trash value.
Is there any way to copy back?

Comment: "it does not work" and "this part has a problem" are not adequate problem descriptions. Please describe more clearly the behaviour of the program.

Comment: `sizeof(temp)` is the size of a pointer.  Also I am suspicious of the calculation in your first memmove: `(p-1) * sizeof(Student) + sizeof(Studient)` is the same as `p * sizeof(Student)`.  Further this whole idea is not going to work (if you intend that the caller sees the changes) - `ptr` is a local variable to your function. You have to redesign how you call the function.